# Grep: find all emails that don't have the pattern

Tags: shell, command-line, grep, regular-expression

I have a directory with a bunch of files and each file contains millions of emails.

I need to get all the emails that don't fit with this pattern

```
 x.y@enron.com
```

x and y are letters.

I have this now but it doesn't match the correct emails

```
grep -P -r -x (?![a-z]*\.[a-z]*@enron)
```

Comment: Single quote your search pattern.  Not only should this not match the correct emails, it should be throwing the following (or similar) error: `-bash: ![a: event not found`.  You are trying to run nonsense commands in a subshell.

Comment: Your grep will need to be a lot more sophisticated to separate out each email from the various files in order to display only those emails that don't have the pattern, versus every *line* as you have it now.

Comment: Emails, as in full messages, or just email _addresses_?

Comment: i am trying this now grep -E -r -x [^.]*@[a-z]*\.com

Comment: how can i rewrite (?![a-z]*\.[a-z]*@enron) to correct it?

Comment: @ilkkachu only email addresses

Answer (score 1):

#### Answer

```
grep -Evr "[a-z]+\.[a-z]+@enron"
```

#### Explanation

`-E` - Use extended regex. (Allow some characters to be used without escaping them)

`-v` - Invert the matches. (Everything that doesn't match the pattern will be shown)

`-r` - Search files recursively.

`[a-z]+\.[a-z]+@enron` - Your regex just with `+` instead of `*`, as I expect that there must be some letters in each section.

Comment: This doesn't work at all.  Maybe you were looking for `grep -Evr`?  This will still show the body of the emails with the x.y@enron addresses though.

Comment: It still wont work though, please test it.

Comment: I had minimal test, can you please give me example on which it doesn't work?

Comment: the -v is not my option. Now i notice that the files also contain the message that users wrote

Comment: This will show the full email files and simply strip out the unwanted email addresses.

Comment: @AndresZW I know it's sensitive data, but can you make us a simple example of 1 file with correct and incorrect emails(imaginary emails, of course)?

Comment: Correct >jone@enron.com, efri@hotmail.com Incorrect>rose.marie@enron.com

Comment: Thank you but that is not helping very much. My current regex catches  that correctly. You mentioned messages in the content as well and that's why I asked you for the sample.